# Php ad every 6th item except first row

Tags: php, arrays, math

I need to add an item every 6th position.

So it would look like this:

```
[
   //item1
   //item2
   //item3
   //item4
   //item5
   //NEW ITEM HERE
   //item7
   //item8
   //item9
   //item10
   //item11
   //NEW ITEM
]
```

I already tried this:

```
foreach($ports as $key => $port)
{
    if($key %9 == 2) {
        $ports->splice($key, 0, [$ads]);
    }
}
```

But that's not working any idea?

Comment: Why not just `%6 == 0`?

Comment: why % 6 == 2? It should be %6 == 0!

Comment: When I try `%6 == 0` it starts (puts it on the 1 position). The first one needs to be at position 6. That's the problem.

Comment: then `if($key %6 == 0 && $key != 0)`

Comment: Then the first item starts at position 7.

Comment: I think it should be `if(!(($key+1)%5)){...}`

Comment: What is supposed to happen with item 6? Should it be deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array_chunk` and add element to each of sub-arrays:

```
$portsChunks = array_chunk($ports, 5); // Split array to sub-arrays of max-5 elements.

// Add new element if chunk is full length.
// Means last one will not receive new element if it's shorter than 5
array_walk($portsChunks, function (&$array) {
    if (count($array) == 5) {
        $array[] = 'New Item';
    }
});

// Use arguments unpacking to pass all chunks to array_merge
$ports = array_merge(...$portsChunk);
```

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4c9506ad0bb3cd19d4db4bb3a7eec7038759a83a)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foreach` loop:

```
$ports = range(1,50);
$new_ports = [];
foreach ($ports as $key => $port) {
    $new_ports[] = $port;
    if(!(($key+1)%5))
        $new_ports[] = 'New item';
}
print_r($new_ports);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I had nearly completed typing. Simple and does the job.

Comment: Yes. But he has a problem with only the first element(when `$key==0`), so this means his array is not associative.

Answer (score 0):

I hope below case solves your problem:

```
$newarr = array();

    $cnt = 1;


    foreach($arr as $key=>$value){

            $newarr[] = $value;

            if($cnt%5 == 0){

            $newarr[] = 'this is new item';

        }

            $cnt++;

    }
print_r($newarr);
```

Comment: Why `echo` and why using own key when you can use `$key`?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $ports = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    $ports = array_chunk($ports, 5);
    foreach ($ports as &$port){
        array_push($port, 'new value');
    }
    unset($port);
    if(count($ports[count($ports)-1]) < 6){
        array_pop($ports[count($ports)-1]);
    }
    $ports = array_merge(...$ports);
```

Comment: Why not `$ports=[range(1,6),range(1,6),range(1,6)]`!

Comment: @Kerkouch         $a = range(1, 6); $ports = [$a, $a, $a]; // [[1-6],[1-6],[1-6]]

Answer (score 0):

you just need a new array to hold all of your data. and then you iterate over your old array and after each 5th position insert a new element. something like this

```
$result = [];
$ports = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
$porstCount = count($ports);
for ($i = 0; $i < $portsCount; $i++) {
    $result[] = $ports[$i];
    if ($i > 0 && $i % 5 === 0) {
        $result[] = 'new element';
    }
}

// $result will be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'new element', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'new element', 11, 12]
```

Comment: Doesn't `0 % 4 === 0`?

Comment: @Justinas indeed. thanks for pointing it. Also changed from 4 to 5, because position is 6th